# Xcode workspace with Unity3D as a sub-project?

Tags: unity, cocos2d-iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

Let's say we're developing a 2D game with Cocos2d-iPhone and UIKit and CoreAnimation. But we're also considering leveraging the 3D capabilities of Unity 3D.

Is it possible that we add the Unity3D-generated Xcode project as a sub-project into the workspace and expose the 3D UI element as some kind of UIView subclass so that the native UIKit and CoreAnimation code could use them without the need to mess up with their underlying Unity3D implementation?

Answer (score -1):

**Well it's possible to combine the languages:**

1. [**integration of Unity-3D with cocos2D**](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/67863-integration-of-Unity-with-cocos2d) @[Unity-3D official forum](http://forum.unity3d.com)

   - **Unity does not offer any kind of source code** for the engine, as such no you can't integrate cocos (or any other engine) into unity nor vice versa
   - **You can use plugins yes and basically run Unity, or pause unity and run cocos,** but you can not use the same assets in unity as in cocos and the build size will grow even further.
   - You will have to ask on the cocos board about cocos stuff I fear
2. If your going to bother to use an advanced engine like `Unity-3D`

   - To take advantage of nice features requires lots of money
   - `Unity-3D` engine has multiple plugins for video and audio doesn't need integration
   - Learning Unity-3D will be difficult
   - Integrating cocos-2d would limit your abilities

---

**I suggest you choose an option:**

1. Stick to `cocos2D` because the combination could cause unwanted problems
2. Move everything over to `Unity-3D` for more control
3. If you have to integrate them, and for more questions try the `Unity-3D` forums.

Comment: Yes, Unity offers source-code, but it's quite an expensive package AFAIK.

Comment: I think its on a "Contact us and we can make a deal" Type deal.